# State seems to be reverting back to its initial state after useeffect is run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, use-effect, use-state

I am having an issue where it seems a state is reverting to its initial state without being prompted to. The state is change in a function, which then triggers a useeffect. The useffect then runs, recognizing and console.logging the update state. Then however, the next call to the function says the state is still in its initial state. My code is below, unfortunately I cant include a full snippet as it includes some things that cannot be shared/run.

Here is where I declare my states:

```
const [playerTeam, setPlayerTeam] = useState({});
const [movement, setMovement] = useState({ active: false, character: null });
```

Here is my useeffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasReference.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("drawing", movement);

    setCharacterUpdate(false);

    mapImage.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = mapImage.width;
      canvas.height = mapImage.height;
      context.drawImage(mapImage, 0, 0);
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(playerTeam)) {
        context.drawImage(
          playerTeam[key].spriteImg,
          playerTeam[key].x,
          playerTeam[key].y
        );
      }
    };
  }, [playerTeam, movement]);
```

Here is where I change states that I expect to trigger the useeffect:

```
function handleClick(canvas, e) {
    console.log(movement);
    //get the coordinates of the user's curson on click
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    let y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    //movement mode is active (last click was a click on an ally character)
    if (movement.active) {
      moveCharacter(x, y);
    }
    //if we arent in movement mode...
    else {
      //cycle through player's team
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(playerTeam)) {
        //if the coordinates of the click are on the same 48 x 48 tile as one of the ally characters
        if (
          x >= playerTeam[key].x &&
          x <= playerTeam[key].x + 47 &&
          y >= playerTeam[key].y &&
          y <= playerTeam[key].y + 47
        ) {
          console.log("Batman!");

          const enterMovement = {
            active: true,
            character: playerTeam[key].name,
          };

          //put us in movement mode
          setMovement(enterMovement);

          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //function for moving the character
  function moveCharacter(x, y) {
    console.log("here");
    let newTeam = playerTeam;
    newTeam[movement.character].x = x - (x % 48);
    newTeam[movement.character].y = y - (y % 48);
    setPlayerTeam(newTeam);
    let exitMovement = { active: false, character: null };
    setMovement(exitMovement);
    console.log(movement, playerTeam["batman"]);
  }
```

Here are some things I noticed that confuse me:

- The handleClick function never reads movement.active as true. The console log at the beginning of handle click shows it is false on every call to the function.
- The useeffect function, however, has a console log in it that shows that the movement field is, in fact, being changed to true. The useeffect runs on each click, indicating that the movement field is in fact changing, but somehow between the useffect triggering and the next click, the movement.active field is reverting back to its initial state.

*The playerTeam state is not empty by the way, it is populated in a separate section of code.

Thanks for any ideas/answers!

Comment: The useEffect you have share is that everything? If so can you please comment out the code after the console.log or can you please add a new console.log at the end of the useEffect snippet and check?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it was 3am when you replied. I have added the console logs like you asked. Same issue is occurring. Here are the console logs, which I updated a bit to hopefully make it easier to understand:

`Beginning of handleclick, movement is: {active: false, character: null}

Batman:  {active: false, character: null}

At beginning of useeffect, here is the movement {active: true, character: 'batman'}

At end of Useeffect, here is the movement: {active: true, character: 'batman'}

Beginning of handleclick, movement is: {active: false, character: null}`

Comment: I also tried using redux state values instead of usestate. The same issue occurs! The handle click function says the movement is false even when the redux devtools extension is showing me the movement.active is true. I am very confused.

Comment: useStates don't immeditaley update. if you want check whether states change or not, can check it with useEffect, ex: `useEffect(() => {console.log("updated",movement) },[movement])`